# What are the best practices of designing a validation message on an iPhone App?

Tags: forms, mobile, iphone, validation, applications

I am working on designing an iPhone app and I need to know which validation message style is the most recommended for the forms included.

I don't prefer to use a pop up window i need something that keeps the user on the same page with minimal distraction.

Comment: I'm not particularly familiar with iOS development. What options are available beyond the pop up?

Comment: I have read an article that shows number of different practices, but yet I need to seek the best one.
http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/07/07/web-form-validation-best-practices-and-tutorials/

Comment: I know these are for web, but It just gives me some hints.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I personally have seen [US2FormValidator](https://github.com/ustwo/US2FormValidator) used in a couple of iPhone apps and its pretty slick. I'm not sure I personally agree with the default icon choice for the error icon, because tends to look a bit like if I touch it, it will delete/clear the field.

I think that library is a great improvement over the default of just popping an alert when something doesn't validate.

Here's some additional usability benefits:

- Validation can occur as the element is blurred without interrupting the user's flow. (Don't have to wait for submit to know what they entered is invalid).
- Errors are visually-related to the field being validated. As opposed to in an alert where it tells you the name of the field, you can actually see which field is invalid.
- User may not need the detailed message to know they did something wrong -- with a solution like this they have the *option* (but aren't forced) to read any detailed message before being able to correct the error themselves.

[Here's a video](http://maniacdev.com/2012/03/open-source-slick-and-easy-to-use-ios-form-validation-library/) I found demoing it in action as well.

[image: US2FormValidator Preview]